# Creating a Custom Silverlight Designer in WPF

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, expression-blend

I need to create a designer for Silverlight in WPF and I’m thinking of a few options

1. Use a **WebBrowser** control,
   display the content there and
   communicate Silverlight using the
   JavaScript Bridge. Not sure if this
   will be enough for the scenarios I
   need to support (see below). This is what KaXaml is doing. SilverlightSpy uses a  a more sophisticated WebBrowser control, but I'm not sure how they communicate with Silverlight.
2. Communicate using **Sockets**
   between the Host and Silverlight.
3. Host the Silverlight runtime (not in
   a browser), but directly using
   **AgCore.dll**. Similar to what sllauncher does for OOB. I imagine
   this is what Blend/VS are doing.
4. Do whatever **Blend or VS** are doing
   which.

I obviously don’t want to go as far as VS and Blend, but I need to support drag and drop of some controls as well as grouping, changing the layout, moving controls in the design surface and obviously updating the Xaml as a result of this actions.

Any ideas, recommendations or pointers on the best way to create a Silverlight Designer in WPF?

Comment: It needs be WPF and not an Silverlight OOB with Elevated privs because....?

Comment: This is an add-in to an existing WPF App. One of the options we are considering is doing all of the designer a SL App hosted using either a WebBrowser or XcpHost, but the problem is that some of the panes need to be docked away from the design surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharpDevelop 4 has a WPF based editor for WPF and Silverlight -> http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. SharpDevelop seems like a great alternative, however, it doesn't support Silverlight.